# Swift: Show success screen after login

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

Here is my code:

```
if(statusCode != 200) {

                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }
            else {

                print("Everything Looks good: \(responseData)")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

            }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)
    }
```

`performSegueWithIdentifier` does not do anything.

**Update**

```
print("Everything Looks good: \(responseData)")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logi‌​n", sender: self)
                })
```

throws

```
2015-07-16 00:40:18.298 phoenix[2750:259334] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<phoenix.LoginViewController: 0x7fab62514d30>) has no segue with identifier 'logi‌​n''
*** First throw call stack:
```

It should not be the case, because
[image]

Comment: Try this, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)})`

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: If it logs `Everything Looks good ..` then make sure the segue name is correct.

Comment: where have you coded success controller's name ? it is showing `login`

Comment: Shouldn't be there something like `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("success", sender: SuccessViewController.self)` ??

Comment: can we take a look at the ID of ViewController in storyboard?

Comment: Try [cleaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073) the cache and build then check again.